# HTML5 date format Android

Tags: php, javascript, android, html, datepicker

Is it possible to change the date format of the HTML5 datepicker?

The default format looks good in Chrome and iOS (`dd-mm-yyyy`) but not in Android (`mm-dd-yyyy`). I cant use a php function to change it after a submit because for example `04-05-2013` could be `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Currently I use this code:

```
<input type="date" name="dueDate" />
```

I looked at all the possible attributes but there isn't something like "format"...

Maybe with javascript? But still, then I need to be able to check the clients input format...

Comment: Before submitting why you cant change it from client side itself ?

Comment: @RajeshCP: I can, but how? How can I know if its in dd/mm/yyyy of in mm/dd/yyyy? Because you cant say which format this daste has for example: 03-04-2013 it could be both... And you can't manipulate the default android date picker...

Comment: You don't want to after setting the date before submitting change the values which ever way you want

Comment: @RajeshCP: Thats what I had in mind, but how? How can I know when a user inserts a date with the time picker, wich format is was? How can I see the difference between dd-mm-yyyy and mm-dd-yyyy? 

For example: If a user inputs 05-06-2013 it could be dd-mm-yyyy as well as mm-dd-yyyy

You see what I mean?

Thanks for the responses :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think input type="date" from html5 is fully compatible with android
as you can see in this page http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html

Comment: that webpage isn't up to date... Im talking about Androis ICS or later. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: ah I see, OK then if I found another solution I'll edit my answer :)